# Disabling tastypie's basic authentication for specific HTTP methods to create users

Tags: python, django, authorization, tastypie

I'm experimenting with Tastypie and Django, and am wondering if what I'd like to do is possible. Let me explain...

I have a custom user resource (and model) as part of my api. I'd like to be able update users through this resource. To ensure that a user can only be updated by it's owner, I've enabled `tastypie.authentication.BasicAuthentication` (this is done through the `put_detail` method).

The problem is that I'd also like to be able to create users through this resource, which can't be done due to `BasicAuthentication` since you need login credentials to access it.

So, I feel as though I've got the following options:

1. Somehow disable authentication for POST requests (doesn't seem possible, from what I've tried).
2. Create a second model resource that doesn't have any form of authentication, but only allows POST requests (I've tried this, but encountered the following issue).

   1. The original model resource is named `user`. Ideally, I'd like this second resource to be named `user/create`, but the URL is never resolved correctly because it's picked up by the `user` model.

This is what I've tried with the 2nd approach...

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    ...

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'users'
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']

    def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        # stub
        return HttpAccepted('User updated.')


class CreateUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'users/create'
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        # No authentication
        list_allowed_methods = ['post']

    def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        # stub
        return HttpCreated('User created.')
```

If I make a POST to `api/v1/users/create`, it is never processed by `CreateUserResource`, since tastypie interprets as a detail view for `UsersResource`, and subsequently I get a 404.

So, is it possible to alter the order in which tastypie searches for the urls for it's resources? The order in which the resources are registered in my `urls.py` file doesn't seem to make a difference. Or are there any alternative suggestions that may be better suited to what I'd like to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do this using approach number 1, by overriding the `dispatch` method for the `UserResource` model. From the docs [[link](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#flow-through-the-request-response-cycle)]:

> - `dispatch` does a bunch of heavy lifting. It ensures:
>
>   - the requested HTTP method is in allowed_methods (`method_check`),
>   - the class has a method that can handle the request (`get_list`),
>   - the user is authenticated (`is_authenticated`),
>   - the user is authorized (`is_authorized`),
>   - & the user has not exceeded their throttle (`throttle_check`).
>
> At this point, dispatch actually calls the requested method
>   (`get_list`).

Now, I wanted to bypass the `is_authenticated` step, but only if the `request` is a "POST" to the 'list' type. The code for my implementation is below...

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from tastypie.http import HttpAccepted, HttpBadRequest, HttpCreated, HttpNoContent, HttpNotImplemented
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from tastypie.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from tastypie.fields import IntegerField, ToManyField
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, convert_post_to_put

from <your_user_module> import User    

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    ...

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'users'
        queryset = User.objects.all()

        authentication = BasicAuthentication()

        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']

    # Bypasses the authentication process if the request is a
    # POST to the 'list'. The code within the 'if' block is
    # taken from 'tastypie.resources.Resource.dispatch()'
    def dispatch_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            request_type = 'list'
            allowed_methods = getattr(self._meta, "%s_allowed_methods" % request_type, None)

            if 'HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE' in request.META:
                request.method = request.META['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE']

            request_method = super(UserResource, self).method_check(request, allowed=allowed_methods)
            method = getattr(self, "%s_%s" % (request_method, request_type), None)

            if method is None:
                raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=HttpNotImplemented())

            # Authentication would normally happen here...
            # ... simply comment it out.
            # super(UserResource, self).is_authenticated(request)
            super(UserResource, self).throttle_check(request)

            # All clear. Process the request.
            request = convert_post_to_put(request)
            response = method(request, **kwargs)

            # Add the throttled request.
            super(UserResource, self).log_throttled_access(request)

            # If what comes back isn't a ``HttpResponse``, assume that the
            # request was accepted and that some action occurred. This also
            # prevents Django from freaking out.
            if not isinstance(response, HttpResponse):
                return HttpNoContent()

            return response
        else:
            return super(UserResource, self).dispatch_list(request, **kwargs)

    # The normally required authentication is bypassed
    # (through the overridden dispatch_list) method above.
    def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Process the request as usual...    
        return HttpCreated('User created.')
```